# Digital persona Applet not loading lib .jar

Tags: java, jsp, applet, noclassdeffounderror, japplet

I have made an applet for capturing finger prints but when I launch in on IE it gives this error:

```
java.lang.noclassdeffounderror: com/digitalpersona/onetouch/capture/event/DPFPDataListener
```

This how the code looks in JSP

```htnl
<applet code="dp.verificationapplet" 
    archive="dp.jar,dpfpverification.jar, dpfpenrollment.jar,dpotapi.jar,dpotjni.jar,dpuareu_jni.jar,dpuareu.jar" 
    width="400" height="350" >
</applet>
```

Comment: Tip: get it working in plain HTML before taking it to JSP. 1) Always copy/paste error and exception output! `noclassdeffounderror` with no upper case letters is a dead giveaway that you typed 'something like' the error.  2) Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form. ..

Comment: .. 3) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/moving-to-a-plugin-free-web).